# Django tuple checking: TEMPLATE_DIRS should be tuple?

Tags: python, django, tuples, django-1.7

I'm trying Django 1.7.

This is my TEMPLATE_DIRS setting:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\', '/')
)
```

which is fine for Django 1.6, but doesn't work for Django 1.7.

Can someone explains this?
Thx!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a trailing `,` for it to be a tuple, see below, the last `,`

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),
)
```

When there's a single element in the tuple you need to leave a trailing comma at the end, e.g. `(a,)` is a tuple with single element `a`, but `(a)` just resolves to whatever `a` is.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Should Work , It Works For Me All The Times

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'templates')
```