# Issue when upgraded Django from 1.6.5 to 1.8.4

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am new to Django Upgrade, i tried upgrading version from 1.6.5 to 1.8.4. I manually intalled 1.8.4 using `sudo python setup.py install` . When I start my pycharm, i get below error. I checked `__init__.py` to check for errors and tried to find out sample file for 1.8.4 for reference. Can some one please explain - How to resolve these errors step by step.

```
Failed to get real commands on module "albatross": python process died with code 1: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ritesh/Development/pycharm-4.5.3/helpers/pycharm/_jb_manage_tasks_provider.py", line 20, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 108, in __init__
    "Please fix your settings." % setting)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The TEMPLATE_DIRS setting must be a tuple. Please fix your settings.
```

**TEMPLATE_DIR**:

```
import os
CURRENT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
 CURRENT_PATH + '/templates'
)
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the backtrace and maybe updating TEMPLATE_DIRS inside settings.py?

Comment: please put your template dirs setting

Comment: @AjayGupta : Added TEMPLATE_DIRS from setting.py

Comment: @AjayGupta: I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340746/django-tuple-checking-template-dirs-should-be-tuple . now its throwing some other  errors. will check them now. If required i'll update my question

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't be using TEMPLATE_DIRS at all in Django 1.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
     CURRENT_PATH + '/templates'
)
```

is *not* a `tuple`, it's just the `CURRENT_PATH + 'templates'` string. What makes a `tuple` is not the parens but the comma, ie:

```
>>> t = ("aaa")
>>> t
'aaa'
>>> type(t)
<type 'str'>
>>> t = "aaa", "bb"
>>> t
('aaa', 'bb')
>>> type(t)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> t = "aaa",
>>> t
('aaa',)
>>> type(t)
<type 'tuple'>
>>>
```

The only exception is the litteral expression for an empty `tuple` which (I assume for readability reasons ?) is spelled `()` instead of `,`

Except for this special case, the parens around a `tuple` litteral are technically useless and are only used for readibility.